# Is there a way to add individual users or a public group to a Library programmatically?

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, tooling-api, public-group

I'm looking for a way to add individual users or a public group to a Library programmatically using Apex.

I've been investigating if there is an API that let me do that, but I had no luck.

I know I can create a public group using Apex, but I don't find a way to link it to a Library.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ContentWorkspaceMember object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacemember.htm) (V40+)

```
insert new ContentWorkspaceMember(
   ContentWorkspaceId = myLibraryId,
   ContentWorkspacePermissionId = myPermissionId,
   MemberId = theGroupId
);
```

where `myPermissionId` has to be queried in advance from [ContentWorkspacePermission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacepermission.htm)